# c++ generic data from keyboad input

Tags: c++, generics, linked-list

Is there a way to get generic data `T` from the keyboard without going into the method call?

Something similar to this:

```
        T data;
        std::cout << "Please enter the data that you would like to delete: ";
        std::cin >> data;
        list.deleteAll(data);
```

Unless I go into the deleteAll method I can't actually create the variable data as a T. Just curious to know if there is a way to do this.

`LinkedList<int> list;`

deleteAll:

```
void deleteAll(T data) {
    int i = 0;
    Node *curr = this->head, *prev;
    while(i < this->size){
        if(data == this[i].data && i == 0){
            this->head = curr->next;
            std::cout << curr->data << endl;
            delete curr;
        }
        else if(data == this[i].data){
            prev = curr;
            prev->next = curr->next;
            std::cout << curr->data << endl;
            delete curr;
            i++;
        }
        else{
            i++;
        }
        this->size--;
    }
}; //delete all
```

Comment: `Unless I go into the deleteAll method I can't actually create the variable data as a T` Why can't you? What's stopping you, exactly? How are `list` and `deleteAll` declared?

Comment: Also, how do you declare the function containing this code?

Comment: I'm trying to create the variable and send it into deleteAll, instead of doing it inside the deleteAll method.

Comment: If `deleteAll()` is a member function, it should be defined with `LinkedList::deleteAll(...)`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice is using list.deleteAll() considered wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a template function:

```
template <class T>
void promptAndDelete(LinkedList<T> list) {
    T data;
    std::cout << "Please enter the data that you would like to delete: ";
    std::cin >> data;
    list.deleteAll(data);
}
```